# Data Migration from MOSS 2007 to SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint

We have done a migration project for one of our client.
This migration was done from MOSS 2007 to SharePoint Enterprise Server 2010.
After the migration was completed we developed lot of new webparts, lists ,application pages in this newly migrated farm in SharePoint Enterprise Server 2010.

However the entire project took around 1 year due to some unavoidable delays. During this one year our client was using MOSS 2007 sites for there work. hence the data in MOSS 2007 farm/sites was continuously updated.

Our client needs to go live in next month and also needs the sites/lists/libraries which are migrated in new SP 2010 farm to be updated as per the MOSS 2007 farm.

Kindly suggest best possible way to achieve this data migration since last 1 year from MOSS 2007 to newly migrated SharePoint Enterprise Server 2010 farm.

Kindly note we have done lot of customization and new developments in newly created SP 2010 farm.

Thanks and regards,
Amien

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at some 3rd party tools for this. I don't think there is a way how to do it by standard sharepoint features, if you want to keep SP 2010 structure and content.

You could write scripts or console app, that would compare libraries in SP2007 and SP2010, but that would require quite amount of work to consider all options.

Also it depends how many these out-of-sync libraries are there and if the structure of these libraries changed (new fields were added, removed, changed).